# JarSigner Ant.signjar working for jar file without dependencies but not working for jar when including dependencies in Gradle Script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-plugin, jarsigner

I am trying to sign a Jar file using **ant.signjar**, it's working fine when I create a Jar file which **doesn't include any dependencies**, but when I **include dependencies** for jar file then it throws me error saying **jarsigner returned: 1**

**Gradle Script(for Jar without Dependencies)**

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.test.webdeployment.ClientApplication'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':dolphin-platform-client-javafx')
}

jar {
    archiveName = 'FXClient.jar'
}

jar.doLast {
    def libFiles = files { file('build/libs').listFiles() }
    libFiles.each {
        ant.signjar(
                alias: "test",
                jar: it,
                keystore: "keystore/test.keystore",
                storepass: "123456",
                keypass: "123456",
                destDir: 'fxclient',
                preservelastmodified: 'true'
        )
    }
}

build.dependsOn jar
```

**Gradle Script(for Jar with Dependencies)**

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.test.webdeployment.ClientApplication'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':dolphin-platform-client-javafx')
}

jar {
    archiveName = 'FXClient.jar'
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

jar.doLast {
    def libFiles = files { file('build/libs').listFiles() }
    libFiles.each {
        ant.signjar(
                alias: "test",
                jar: it,
                keystore: "keystore/test.keystore",
                storepass: "123456",
                keypass: "123456",
                destDir: 'fxclient',
                preservelastmodified: 'true'
        )
    }
}

build.dependsOn jar
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':client:jar'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:256)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:253)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:175)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
Caused by: : jarsigner returned: 1
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:644)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:670)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:496)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SignJar.signOneJar(SignJar.java:534)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SignJar.execute(SignJar.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:103)
        at client_65u3l6p4lilyt8z1uffayl9g$_run_closure4$_closure8.doCall(/Users/ganeshdeshvini/work/canoo_projects/dolphin-platform-examples/platform-examples/web-deployment-example/client/client.gradle:32)
        at client_65u3l6p4lilyt8z1uffayl9g$_run_closure4.doCall(/Users/ganeshdeshvini/work/canoo_projects/dolphin-platform-examples/platform-examples/web-deployment-example/client/client.gradle:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:596)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:577)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 70 more
```

Please let me know how to get the JarSigner work for signing Jar files which has dependencies included, as I am new to gradle scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution, added manifest code

**Final Gradle Script**

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.test.webdeployment.ClientApplication'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':dolphin-platform-client-javafx')
}

jar {
    archiveName = 'fxclient.jar'
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

jar.doLast {
    def libFiles = files { file('build/libs').listFiles() }
    libFiles.each {

        ant.jar(destfile: it, update: true) {
            delegate.manifest {
                attribute(name: 'permissions', value: 'all-permissions')
                attribute(name: 'codebase', value: '*')
            }
        }

        ant.signjar(
                alias: "test",
                jar: it,
                keystore: "keystore/test.keystore",
                storepass: "123456",
                keypass: "123456",
                destDir: 'fxclient',
                preservelastmodified: 'true'
        )
    }
}

build.dependsOn jar
```